# Синтаксическая ошибка '->'

Tags: php, php7

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    <?php
require_once 'login.php';
$conn = new mysqli($hn, $un, $pw, $db);
if ($conn->connect_error) die($conn->connect_error);

$query = "SELECT * FROM classics";
$result = $conn->query($query);

if (!$result) die ($conn-> error);

$rows = $result->num_rows;

for ($j = 0; $j < $rows; ++$j) 
{
    $result->data_seek($j);
    (16 строка)echo 'Author: ' . result->fetch_assoc()['author'] . '<br>';
    $result->data_seek($j);
    echo 'Title: ' . result->fetch_assoc()['title'] . "<br>";
    $result->data_seek($j);
    echo 'Category: ' . result->fetch_assoc()['category'] . "<br>";
    $result->data_seek($j);
    echo 'Year: ' . result->fetch_assoc()['year'] . "<br>";
    $result->data_seek($j);
    echo 'ISBN: ' . result->fetch_assoc()['isbn'] . "<br><br>";
}
$result->close();
$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: Вы пропустили знак `$` здесь `result->fetch_assoc()['author']` -> `$result->fetch_assoc()['author']`. И везде в следующих строках.

Comment: @ Raz Galstyan,да действительно так. Спасибо большое)
Причем самое интересное то что этот пример кода с книги Робина Никсона и там этого $ нет

Comment: Ошибки могут быть у всех.

Comment: @RazGalstyan согласна